# Ionic 3 inaccurate geolocation

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm currently working with the native geolocation for ionic 3

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

To get the user position I'm doing this:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```

Now my problem is that I'm getting a very low accuracy, meaning that my position is off by at least 300 meters.

If I try to open the google maps application my location is totally correct, then when I try to calculate it a second later with my application is again wrong.

Any suggestion?

Comment: do you have the right permissions? if not geolocation falls back to mobile provider data.


`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have all the permissions needed. You can use the cordova diagnostic plugin to make runtime permissions, check for location enabled, connect to location settings if it's disabled and more.

Secondly you can pass options with highAccuracy(=GPS) in the getCurrentPosition function:

```
let options = {
   enableHighAccuracy: true,
   timeout: 30000,
   maximumAge: 60000
};
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use constructor, private `geoloc: Geolocation`

```
   this.geoloc.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      var myLocation= new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```

Use myLocation